# Spring Boot @Controller not working when deploy on Tomcat standalone

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have an Spring Boot Application + ThymeLeaf, with @RestController and @Controller, everything work fine with tomcat embedded but when I deploy my app with war file to Tomcat 8.5 @Controller class not working @RestController is working fine, when I go to any page with controller use @Controller I have 404 error.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>boot-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>web</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>[5.0.2,5.1.47)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                    <warName>skillinventory</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/resources/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/web-si/src/main/web/dist/FrontEnd/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my Spring Boot app class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Value("${cas.service}")
    private String service;

    @Value("${cas.loginUrl}")
    private String loginUrl;

    @Value("${cas.cas30ServiceTicketValidator}")
    private String cas30ServiceTicketValidator;

    @Value("${cas.createAuthorityList}")
    private String createAuthorityList;

    @Value("${cas.key}")
    private String key;

    @Value("${cas.logoutFilterLink}")
    private String logoutFilterLink;

    @Value("${cas.setFilterProcessesUrl}")
    private String setFilterProcessesUrl;

    @Value("${cas.setCasServerUrlPrefix}")
    private String setCasServerUrlPrefix;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceProperties serviceProperties() {
        ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
        serviceProperties.setService(service);
        serviceProperties.setSendRenew(false);
        return serviceProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(ServiceProperties sP) {
        CasAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new CasAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        entryPoint.setLoginUrl(loginUrl);
        entryPoint.setServiceProperties(sP);
        return entryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public TicketValidator ticketValidator() {
        return new Cas30ServiceTicketValidator(cas30ServiceTicketValidator);
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {
        CasAuthenticationProvider provider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService());
        provider.setKey(key);
        return provider;
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationUserDetailsService<CasAssertionAuthenticationToken> customUserDetailsService() {
        return token -> {
            AttributePrincipal principal = token.getAssertion().getPrincipal();
            String name = principal.getName();
            return new User(name, "pwd", AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(createAuthorityList));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityContextLogoutHandler securityContextLogoutHandler() {
        return new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public LogoutFilter logoutFilter() {
        LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter(logoutFilterLink, securityContextLogoutHandler());
        logoutFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(setFilterProcessesUrl);
        return logoutFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter() {
        SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter = new SingleSignOutFilter();
        singleSignOutFilter.setCasServerUrlPrefix(setCasServerUrlPrefix);
        singleSignOutFilter.setIgnoreInitConfiguration(true);
        return singleSignOutFilter;
    }

    @EventListener
    public SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener singleSignOutHttpSessionListener(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        return new SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener();
    }
}
```

My security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    public SpringSecurityConfig(CasAuthenticationProvider
                                        casAuthenticationProvider,
                                AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
        this.authenticationProvider = casAuthenticationProvider;
        this.authenticationEntryPoint = authenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v1/datas/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .regexMatchers("/")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .regexMatchers("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws
            Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }


    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(authenticationProvider));
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter(ServiceProperties serviceProperties) throws Exception {
        CasAuthenticationFilter filter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return filter;
    }
```

My controller with @Controller :

```
@Controller
public class ManagerDataController {

    @Value("${theme.root}")
    private String themeRoot;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hr/skilldatas", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String goProgessData(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("themeRoot", themeRoot);
        return "data-process";
    }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/hr/datas", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String goDataManager(Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("themeRoot", themeRoot);
      return "datamanager";
  }

}
```

I don't know why it working fine with tomcat embeded but tomcat standalone?

Comment: Looking at your dependencies and plugins I would say first start by fixing those. The fact that you declared a version for `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` makes me wonder if you have mixed versions. The inclusion of `spring-context` makes me wonder why, as that is included in the starters already present. You shouldn't need the war plugin (as the Spring Boot plugin takes care of that and actually places it in a different directory. ). Finally check your logs on why you get the 404, there should be information in the logs, maybe enable DEBUG logging to have more information.

Comment: Thank you sir, but what you mean have mixed version, I don't understand that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out that because I declare thymeleaf dependency scope is provided, it not Spring false, after I change scope to compile it working now.